# Accessing a div tab from another page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bit of a code from twitters bootstrap, a sort of navbar tabs.

These tabs seems to be retrieved using the #tab feature. Lets say this menu is on a file called index.php

```
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <p>I'm in Section A.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
          <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But how can i from another page like main.php jump straight to the tab2? u get my point?
I was trying:

```
<a href="index.php#tab2">link to tab2</a>
```

or

```
<a href="index.php#tab2" data-toggle="tab">link to tab2</a>
```

but it's not working..., don't know if the data-toggle="tab" is needed somehow?

any hints appreciated!

Comment: If you would use jquery.tabs() (found in jquery ui) then it works.

Comment: hmmm, ok how would I do that? I'm kind of a newbie...

Comment: jtheman: any hints on how I can do that? my knowledge is kind of 'non-existent' in this area!

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery easytabs plugin solves this quite easy. Read more and download plugin: http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/ Remember to install jquery and other Javascripts

HTML:

```
<head> <!-- other markup -->
   <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/javascripts/jquery.hashchange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/javascripts/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
             $('#tab-container').easytabs();
       });
   </script>
</head>
<body>



<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
<ul class='etabs'>
  <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-html">HTML Markup</a></li>
  <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-js">Required JS</a></li>
  <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-css">Example CSS</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs1-html">
  <h2>HTML Markup for these tabs</h2>
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="tabs1-js">
  <h2>JS for these tabs</h2>
  <!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="tabs1-css">
  <h2>CSS Styles for these tabs</h2>
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.etabs { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.tab { display: inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; background: #eee; border: solid 1px #999; border-bottom: none; -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }
.tab a { font-size: 14px; line-height: 2em; display: block; padding: 0 10px; outline: none; }
.tab a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.tab.active { background: #fff; padding-top: 6px; position: relative; top: 1px; border-color: #666; }
.tab a.active { font-weight: bold; }
.tab-container .panel-container { background: #fff; border: solid #666 1px; padding: 10px;    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; }
```

Comment: Hi again, thx for keeiping up with me, im using bootstrap, how would that markup look like? Is there a way to find that in the bootstrap-tabs.js?

Comment: @FredrikTornell Aha, even more easy, then you already has jQuery UI tabs implemented. So to access hashes see my other answer...

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap and the included jQuery UI, implementation of navigational hashes is pretty simple. Use a Javascript like this

```
$(function () {
  var gotoTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
  gotoTab && gotoTab.tab('show');
});
```

However, this doesn't work with history or the back button. So this is a downside of using javascript for tab navigation. I dont know if there might be any other solution out there?

Comment: And that javascript should be placed in the head section? and then I could use a link to access page two like index.php#tab2 correct?

Comment: trying index.php?id=38#add_comment and add_comment is the id of that tab I wanna access... dosnt work, I put yer code in the header

Comment: @FredrikTornell Sure, in the head or wherever actually. Have you loaded the tabs code before?  Try just $('#tab3').tab('show'); in the function call and see if this gets default on pageload? Maybe you could post all your javascript code also to the question above?